# Blank pages from logged in views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I have an MVC application which displays the login page and the reset password page fine, and when I fill in the reset password form, an email gets correctly sent to me. So I know the database connection is fine and the web.config is being read correctly.

However, when I log in to the application, I get a blank page back. Once I have logged in, the login & logout pages subsequently return blank. I can open an incognito tab and get the login & logout pages again, so it seems like an issue to do with the cookie/authentication - i.e. once logged in, it's sending the cookie, but somewhere in the pipeline something is failing when validating(?) the cookie.

I should add that this website works fine on my laptop but when I publish to my host, it has this behavior.

I wanted to make sure the correct route/controller was being used, so I created a very simple "Test" controller & View. If I navigate to the url `http://www.example.com/test` then I get the error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

However, this works correctly on localhost - i.e. only when published does it have this error. On localhost I see the correct View contents. I'm not sure if this is related?

Strangely the Physical Path that it's looking for the "Test" config file is in:

```
Config File    \\?\D:\Websites\example.com\httpdocs\test\web.config
```

I.e. it's looking in the test folder, although the test is just a Route for a View/Controller.

I can't work out what's gone wrong with my (previously working) website?

Comment: Have a look at the IIS configuration, maybe the paths are all messed up.

Comment: @JeffWatkins What do you mean, the IIS configuration? It's on a shared hosting provider so I don't have full IIS access. (Works fine on localhost development, though. And was working for weeks up to a few hours ago)